# Rails uninitialized constant for an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, rails-activerecord, simple-form

So there is a plethora of questions about the "uninitialized constant" error, and it's almost always due to an incorrectly specified association (e.g. plural model names instead of singular, incorrectly writing your association inside the model, etc). My models and form look spotless, so maybe this is something new (or I'm blind)?

A "user" has one "move". A "move" has many "neighborhood_preferences", and through this, many "neighborhoods".

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :move
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :move, allow_destroy: true
end

class Move < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :neighborhood_preferences
  has_many :neighborhoods, through: :neighborhood_preferences
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :neighborhood_preferences, allow_destroy: true
end

class NeighbhoodPreference < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :neighborhood
  belongs_to :move
end

class Neighborhood < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  has_many :neighborhood_preferences
  has_many :moves, through: :neighborhood_preferences
end
```

View:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user, :html => { class: :form } ) do |u| %>

<%= u.fields_for :move do |m| %>
<div>
    <%= m.label :start_date %>
    <%= m.date_field :start_date %>
</div>
<div>
    <%= m.label :end_date %>
    <%= m.date_field :end_date %>
</div>
<div>
    <%= m.label :min_price %>
    <%= m.text_field :min_price %>
</div>
<div>
    <%= m.label :max_price %>
    <%= m.text_field :max_price %>
</div>
<%= m.association :neighborhood_preferences %>
<% end %>


<%= u.submit "Save Changes" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in class name `NeighbhoodPreference`.

Comment: You beat me to it :-)